# Bootstrap3 javascript hide/show error message

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with Bootstrap 3.
I would like to show a DIV when there is an error detected in a form with javascript.
The control seems to be ok but the DIV doesn't show.
Thank's in advance

html code :

```
<div class="alert1 alert-danger hidden">You have to ... !</div>
```

javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
     $("#form1").on("submit", function(){
      if($("#dossier_pro_numero_rue").val().length < 1){
       $("div.control-group").addClass("alert-danger");
       $("div.alert1").show("slow").delay(3000).hide("slow");
      return false;}
     });
    });
</script>
```

EDIT :

but finally, my problem is a conflict between Bootstrap (3.1) and jquery.

If I put in my head page this line :

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

it's ok

but if I put also this line :

```
<link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

it's wrong my error message doesn't show

The same code with Bootstrap version 2.x is ok.

You can test on ...
 http://jsbin.com/siwik/1/edit?html,css,output

It's ok, but if you add library Bootstrap lastest verion, it doesn't run

Do you see why ?

EDIT :

I have found the solution which is very simple and logical :

you don't put 'hidden' :

```
    <div class="alert1 alert-danger">You have to ... !</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.alert1` instead of `div.alert1`

```
   $(".alert1").show("slow").delay(3000).hide("slow");
```

or id attribute selector for calling the DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#form1").on("submit", function(e){
      if($("#dossier_pro_numero_rue").val().length < 1){
          e.preventDefault();
          $("div.control-group").addClass("alert-danger");
          $("div.alert1").show("slow").delay(3000).hide("slow");
      }
 });
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Vb8j8/